# Host website from portable drive connected to router

Tags: router, apache-http-server, xampp, web-hosting

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but have not been able to find a solution on here, YouTube, or any place else.

I am trying to host a website from an external hard drive attached to my router via the USB port on the router.

Currently I have it hosted on my desktop using XAMPP and it works perfectly ... until I turn off my computer or walk away for more than 30 minutes and it goes into sleep mode. I could just never turn off my computer and disable sleep mode but that uses a lot of power for no reason.

Is this even a possibility? If not, please explain why. If so please let me know how or give me a link that gives me a walk through.

This shouldn't matter but if anyone needs it for any reason, my router is a TP-LINK AC1750, the external drive is a 500GB HDD that I took out of an old laptop.

Comment: To "host" a website you need a "server", which is a computer, executing a webserver program.  A disk drive only stores data.  It requires a computer to retrieve that data.  A disk drive by itself is not sufficient to "host" a website.

Comment: @sawdust the router is certainly enough computer to run (some) webserver programs.  the real question is, does the firmware provide such a webserver already (and how to enable it), or is there a 3rd-party firmware option (ddwrt, openwrt, etc) that would?

Comment: Most (perhaps all?) wireless routers and access points have a basic, built-in webserver to host the device's configuration page(s).  *"the real question is ..."* -- So why are you asking this in a follow-up comment; why isn't this question part of your original post?

Comment: You could check: http://serverfault.com/questions/436810/host-a-simple-website-on-a-wifi-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, your router alone does run a webserver (configuration tools) however it probably won't take to running your PHP, etc. from XAMPP.

Spend $50 and get a Raspberry Pi with a case, etc. Install Raspbian, and treat it like any other Debian machine - install apache2, php for apache, mysql, php-mysql, and you are off and running.  Power it from the router supplied USB, plug it into the router with a short network cable.

Comment: Thank you. This is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: So I got myself a Raspberry Pi and found this tutorial on YouTube that dose a good job walking you through the process of doing this. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzojwG7OB7c